# Sprite-based 2D animation software

Tags: animation

I'm making an intro to my game and I need software to do so. I'm looking for sprite-based software where every sprite can have own frame loop plus animated properties like position/rotation/scale/opacity.

My target is to create GBA-like intro [like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N03jUDnPveA).

Ultimately I need it to be exportable as video file (avi/mp4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Synfig Studio](https://www.synfig.org/) is generally the go-to OSS tool for 2D animation

It is certainly a bit overkill, but [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) is a very capable animation tool, and while totally geared towards 3D animation it can easily make 2D as well

Recent versions of [Krita](https://krita.org/en/) introduced basic 2D animation capabilites. Should suffice for your intended results.

Comment: Hi @DuarteFarrajotaRamos. I like to use Blender for pretty much everything but Blender does not have frame-by-frame loops and workaround are extremely messy, Synfig looks good. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Synfig looks good but i have one question : Do you know how i can swap sprite for different one as keyframe ? I like to make retro looking animation like [this one](https://pa1.narvii.com/6542/4916704644971d9c20c494f9775f59e1d31d68d4_hq.gif) and let it loop inside bigger animation

Comment: I have never used Synfig myself

Comment: Looks like i was looking on wrong place. With right keyworlds google find it quite fase. If anyone have same problem [this page](https://wiki.synfig.org/Switch_Group_Layer) shows how you can do it.